# Bound on the Jacobian of a contraction

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

> Let $\varphi: \Bbb R^d \to \Bbb R^d$ be a continuously differentiable contraction with a contraction constant $0 \le q < 1$. Show that $||\varphi'(z)v|| \le q||v||$ for all $v, z \in \Bbb R^d$.

My attempt:

$$\varphi (v) = \varphi(z) + \varphi'(z)(v - z) + o(||v-z||) \iff$$
$$\varphi (v) - \varphi(z) =  \varphi'(z)(v - z) + o(||v-z||)$$

Thus, since $\varphi$ is a contraction:
$$
||\varphi'(z)(v - z) + o(||v-z||)|| \le q||v - z|| \le q||v|| + q||z||
$$
So it follows that
$$
||\varphi'(z)(v - z) + o(||v-z||)|| - q||z|| \le q||v||
$$
I need to show the following:
$$
||\varphi'(z)v|| \le ||\varphi'(z)(v - z) + o(||v-z||)|| - q||z||
$$
which simplifies to
$$
0 \le ||\varphi'(z)z + o(||v-z||)|| - q||z||
$$

Which is where I got stuck.
Am I on the right track? How can I finish this proof?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Let $\varphi: \Bbb R^d \to \Bbb R^d$ be a continuously differentiable contraction with a contraction constant $0 \le q < 1$. Show that $||\varphi'(z)v|| \le q||v||$ for all $v, z \in \Bbb R^d$.

First, note that what is required to be proved is equivalent to
$$
||\varphi'(z)u|| \le q
$$
for all $u$ such that $\|u\|=1$. Then, I fix what you write:

$$\varphi (v) = \varphi(z) + \varphi'(z)(v - z) + o(||v-z||) \iff$$
$$\varphi (v) - \varphi(z) =  \varphi'(z)(v - z) + o(||v-z||)$$

Thus, since $\varphi$ is a contraction, it follows that
$$
||\varphi'(z)(v - z) || \le q||v - z|| + o(||v-z||)
$$
Set $v:=z+t u$, $t>0$ and $||u||=1$. The previous relation gives
$$
||\varphi'(z) t u || \le q t + o(t)
$$
Divide both sides by $t$ to get
$$
||\varphi'(z) u || \le q + o(t)/t
$$
Take the limit for $t\to 0^+$ to conclude.

Comment: The reason it is equivalent to $||\varphi'(z)u||\le q$ is because $v = k\cdot u$ for some scalar $k$ and unitary vector $u$, and the $k$'s cancel out in the inequality. That is a clever argument, thank you.

Comment: Equivalently, the inequality is trivial if v is zero, otherwise you can divide both members for the norm of v which, being a scalar, can be put inside the norm brackets. Hopefully I explained what I meant :)